# Looking for story about the structure and geometry of stories that is itself a Möbius strip

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm pretty sure I read this short story in Analog SF, probably before 2010 and possibly much earlier.

The story is structured as several interwoven subplot lines, the initial one (as I recall) being an academic discussion about the correspondence between geometry and story/narrative structure, with one person challenging the other to find a story that corresponds to a Möbius strip.  The story itself turns out to be such a story.

I believe one of the subplot lines was a love story.

Comment: Nice and crazy idea! Sounds a bit like Borges, but too late to be him.

Comment: Looks like it's mentioned [here](http://www.epinions.com/review/mags-Analog_Science_Fiction/21342222/870253) but not identified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know this one personally, but I will make a guess based on the clues you've provided: Hilbert Schenck's "The Geometry of Narrative," which, [according to ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49423), appeared in Analog's Aug 1983 issue and was a Hugo Award contender the following year.

As the only online summary I found phrases it:

> This story begins with a character who is a graduate student of
> English proposing to his professor a new geometric approach to
> literary analysis. As he points out, this has been used to some
> limited degree in the past: merely the one dimensional geometry of a
> story as a line segment representing linear passage of time, or the
> planar graph of the "arc" of the storyline building to a local maximum
> at the climax. However, in the story, the character proposes
> applications of higher dimensional geometry (and more complicated
> topologies as well). In particular, he discusses the role of the
> tesseract in analyzing Hamlet, and is ready with an example when his
> professor challenges him to apply the topology of the Möbius strip to
> literature.